# RPM installer failing

Tags: rpm

Odd issue. The RPM installer is installing everything fine but is returning an error code 21. Meaning all of the packages are failing to install. Does anyone have any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: do you get anything pertinent when using the `-v` or `-vv` options?

Comment: Had to re-format in the end :(.

Answer (score 1):

Try each package individually until you find the one that fails.
If they all fail then the problem is with your rpm database (which is why --rebuilddb was suggested above), otherwise you will find which package has a problem (and you can try downloading another version/another one)
Obviously you will need to install the leaves first.

Are you using rpm from the command line? Why not use yum or yast or whatever your distro provides? (which you did not specify)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to rebuild the database using rpm --rebuilddb

Comment: no, same error but thanks.